# Moving vertical axis to left side of a plot

Tags: plotting, formatting

I am trying to make a plot of two separate lists of points that have already been created. The lists are named `c` and `d`. Here is the current code:

```
Show[ListPlot[c, Filling -> Axis], ListPlot[d, Filling -> Axis], PlotRange -> All]
```

When I use this code, I get the following plot

[image]

This plot is fine, but I am interested in moving the y-axis to the left side like a plot typically has. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `AxesOrigin -> {2700, 0}`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! That worked like a charm (although the axis needs to be at closer to 2625).

Comment: You may also like `Frame->True, Axes->False`

Answer (score 1):

```
c = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{2600, 3000}, 10], RandomReal[.5, 10]}];
d = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{3000, 3250}, 10], RandomReal[.5, 10]}];

Show[ListPlot[c, Filling -> Axis], ListPlot[d, Filling -> Axis], 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[c, Filling -> Axis], ListPlot[d, Filling -> Axis], 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {2600, 0}]
```

[image]